# spring-data multiple data source configuration run but insert in wrong datasource

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, datasource

## Configuration

I have followed this tutorial to configure two data sources in spring-data :

https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7

The tomcat start and the two databases are initialized with flyway with success.

The first DataSource configuration look like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableMybatisRepositories(
        value = "com.domain.api.userManagement.repository",
        mapperLocations = {
                "classpath*:/mappers/userManagement/*Mapper.xml",
                "classpath*:/beforemappers/userManagement/*Mapper.xml"
        }
)
public class UserManagementDbConfig {

    @Value("${api.db.userManagement.version}")
    private String version;

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "api.db.userManagement")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("userManagement")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
        final SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return sessionFactory;
    }


    @Bean
    public SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplate(SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory) {
        return new SqlSessionTemplate(sqlSessionFactory);
    }

    @Bean(initMethod = "migrate")
    public Flyway flyway() throws SQLException {
        Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
        flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);
        flyway.setLocations("classpath:db/migration/userManagement");
        flyway.setSqlMigrationPrefix("V");
        flyway.setSqlMigrationSuffix(".sql");
        flyway.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        flyway.setValidateOnMigrate(false);
        flyway.setOutOfOrder(true);
        flyway.setTargetAsString(version);
        flyway.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return flyway;
    }
}
```

And the second DataSource:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableMybatisRepositories(
        value = "com.domain.api.companyManagement.repository",
        mapperLocations = {
                "classpath*:/mappers/companyManagement/*Mapper.xml",
                "classpath*:/beforemappers/companyManagement/*Mapper.xml"
        }
)
public class CompanyManagementDbConfig {

    @Value("${api.db.companyManagement.version}")
    private String version;

    @Bean(name = "companyManagementDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "api.db.companyManagement")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("companyManagement")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean(name = "companyManagementSqlSessionFactory")
    public SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
        final SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean(name = "companyManagementSqlSessionTemplate")
    public SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplate(SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory) {
        return new SqlSessionTemplate(sqlSessionFactory);
    }


    @Bean(initMethod = "migrate", name = "companyManagementFlyway")
    public Flyway flyway() throws SQLException {
        Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
        flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);
        flyway.setLocations("classpath:db/migration/companyManagement");
        flyway.setSqlMigrationPrefix("V");
        flyway.setSqlMigrationSuffix(".sql");
        flyway.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        flyway.setValidateOnMigrate(false);
        flyway.setOutOfOrder(true);
        flyway.setTargetAsString(version);
        flyway.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return flyway;
    }
}
```

This is how I wrote the service in charge of the insert:

```
@Service
public class TestServiceImpl extends AbstractCrudService<TestRepository, Test, Long> implements TestService {

  @Autowired
  public TestServiceImpl(TestRepository repository) {
    super(repository);
  }

  @Override
  @Transactional("companyManagement")
  public void insert(Test user) {
    super.insert(user);
  }

  @Override
  @Transactional("companyManagement")
  public void updateIgnore(Test user) {
    super.updateIgnore(user);
  }
}
```

application.yml:

```
server:
  port: 8080
  session:
    timeout: -1

api:
  db:
    userManagement:
      version: 0.0.17
      url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:3333/UM?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci&characterSetResults=utf8&characterEncoding=UTF-8
      username: ******
      password: ******
      driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
      minIdle: 0
      maxIdle: 10
      maxActive: 50
      maxWait: 6000
      testOnBorrow: true
      validationQuery: SELECT 1
      timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 1800000
      numTestsPerEvictionRun: 50
      minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 10
      testWhileIdle: true
    companyManagement:
      version: 0.0.17
      url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:3334/CM?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci&characterSetResults=utf8&characterEncoding=UTF-8
      username: ******
      password: ******
      driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
      minIdle: 0
      maxIdle: 10
      maxActive: 50
      maxWait: 6000
      testOnBorrow: true
      validationQuery: SELECT 1
      timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 1800000
      numTestsPerEvictionRun: 50
      minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 10
      testWhileIdle: true
```

## Result

```
Fri Nov 03 17:18:46 ICT 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
### Error updating database. Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "cm_test" does not exist Position: 13 ### The error may involve com.domain.api.companyManagement.domain.Test._insert-Inline ### The error occurred while setting parameters ### SQL: insert into "cm_test"("name") values(?) ### Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "cm_test" does not exist Position: 13 ; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "cm_test" does not exist Position: 13
```

This repository should be trying to insert in the 2nd datasource but it try to use the 1st (main) data source.

## Reproduction

url: https://github.com/kopax/spring-data-mybatis-test
You need to start the two database using `docker-compose up -d` or manually without docker.

How did you manage to use multiple DataSource ?

Comment: can you share you application.yml/.properties file?

Comment: @TurbutAlin I have added the relevant part of my `application.yml`

Comment: two other things:
- what about the default spring.datasource? is it initialized?
- basePackages scan is missing from your type of configuration. I see that it has mapperLocations. Not sure if that does the trick. Maybe I will find some time later to try locally.

Comment: I have not used the properties `spring.datasource` but instead `api.db.userManagement`. basePackage scan happen in `Application.java` using `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.domain.api.userManagement","com.domain.api.companyManagement"})`

Comment: Please add qualifier for the transactionManager and use it on your. method transactional annotation.

Comment: How to use it on my method transactional annotation please? I have tried to add `@Qualifier("companyManagementTransactionManager")` on the `transactionManager` method and  `@Transactional("companyManagementTransactionManager")` on my `insert` method and nothing change.

Answer (score 0):

In case of using two DBs separate TransactionManager-s should be created and specified

```
@Bean(name = "companyTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() 
{
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
}
```

RoleServiceImpl

```
 @Override
 @Transactional("companyTransactionManager", readOnly = true)
 public Role getByName(String name) {
```

Comment: For naming the **transactionManager** Should I use `@Qualifier` as recommended by @TurbutAlin, or `@Bean` as recommended by you?

Comment: @BigDong you should use Bean (name = ) for naming. Qualifier is for specifying the concrete bean where there are some of them of the same type. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html

Comment: I have interfaces where I have no method like `public class UserServiceImpl extends AbstractCrudService<UserRepository, User, Long> implements UserService {}`, how can I directly set the transactionManager for all the methods ?

Comment: I also encounter issue like `No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: transactionManager,companyManagement` after settings `@Bean(name = "myService")` with and without `@Qualifier("namemyService")` . It's diffintly playing with the right settings but I can't achieve a runnable example

Comment: For my interface without method issue, should I create a `public abstract class AbstractCompanyManagementCrudService` and annotate all the method for my DataSource here?

Comment: Please, name the transactionManager with Bean(name = ...) attribute. Than use the same name as value for Transactional at service implementations. I told no word about interfaces and Qualifier in my answer.

Comment: I know I am not trying to make you waste your time it's just that if you mind have a look at my test repo? I am playing with the configuration you gave me in every possible way and I only get errors, I can't even get the source from the first dataSource because of unfonctional annotation`@Transactional("companyTransactionManager")`

Comment: @BinDong Updated my answer. There should be correct datasource for the transactionManager.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158168/discussion-between-bigdong-and-andriy-slobodyanyk).

Comment: I have tried all of these combinaison. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have this problem because you have bean with name `dataSorce` in both configs and after creation of Spring Context only one bean with the same name can be present. Try to rename you beans maybe that's will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Tbe problem for me was that in all tutorial I read, the didn't see transactionManager needed `@Primary`.

As soon as I added `@Primary` on `transactionManager` in my main DB, it worked!